# Outlining Structures for Romance Novels

Tags: outline, romance

I'm familiar with the 12 step outline process for heroic fantasy novels, but is there an equivalent outline structure for Romance novels?  By this I mean novels like those produced by Nicholas Sparks, not highly erotic adult novels.

Comment: A and B meet. A and B fall in love. Optional: A and B enjoy snugglebunnies. Obstacle gets between A and B. A and/or B overcome obstacle. Omnia vincit amor.

Comment: @Lauren, this is really an answer, not a comment. Just because it's quick doesn't mean it should be a comment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "12 step outline process for heroic fantasy novels". Could you point out a good source?

Comment: @what Maybe the OP meant the Hero's Journey?

Comment: But that's not outlining in twelve steps (e.g. "first you write down the beginning, second you write down the end, third you list your characters, ..."), but a plot with twelve stages.

Comment: @what What you suggest is a process for *any* novel. "Outline process for *heroic fantasy novel*" sounds like "plotting tool" to me.

Comment: I think the usual way is "boy-being meets girl-being under a silvery moon which then explodes for no adequately explored reason." Oh wait, that's Disaster Area songs.

Answer (score 5):

A and B meet. A and B fall in love. Optional: A and B enjoy snugglebunnies. Obstacle gets between A and B. A and/or B overcome obstacle. Omnia vincit amor.

(since it was requested that I turn this into an answer)

Comment: You should turn it into a comment ;)

Comment: @JohnSmithers Poof! It's a comment. I traveled back in time to October and posted it above. :P

Answer (score 2):

I found a good structure for Romance novels in the book *Romancing the Beat* by Gwen Hayes. It's available on Amazon. She lays out a four-part structure with five key beats per section. I've found it useful in thinking through all the in-betweens of boy-meets-boy, boy-loses-boy, boy-gets-boy-in-the-end.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly you should have in my mind what you want to write about. Try to imagine the characters; their names and how they look like. Try to imagine what type of individual each character it is. Start with a few topics that later will be developed into many why, where, how and what and because. Don't be afraid to google synonyms. Try to write small sentences or paragraphs. And read other heroic fantasy novels. Imagine some sort of conflict. There is no  perfect formula for this. Try to build details about your story. You should also find a writing routine that works for you. Do some research. Use the library. When you feel ready, sit down and begin writing the first draft of your novel. Set small goals  to keep yourself motivated. Practice self-editing. Print out your novel and read it aloud :) Consider trying to publish your novel.

Comment: Welcome to Writers! While your answer is good general advice for writing fantasy novels, the question asks about outlining systems for romance novels.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Actually I think that is a good base for a novel.There is no actual system, only interpretation from each person.I mentioned a possible process of writing for the outlining system. So I don't agree with you Neil Fein. And thank you for the welcome part. Have a good day.